# Too many levels of symbolic links @ rb_sysopen - tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, sidekiq, apache-mina

I have deployed the rails application in staging. The application is running fine except for the `sidekiq`.

In my `sidekiq.log`, I see the following line,

> Too many levels of symbolic links @ rb_sysopen - tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid

I have added the below lines in `deploy.rb` file, with corresponding lines to stop and start the sidekiq server. I am not getting any error while deploying using `mina deploy`.

```
to :launch do
      invoke :'sidekiq:stop'
      invoke :'sidekiq:start'
end
```

In `sidekiq.rb` file, I have set `user, password` for the `Sidekiq::Web`

I am unable to find the reason for this, I tried to `mina deploy` again but the `sidekiq` process didnot get started in the server.

I searched through some blogs and SO questions [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491074/usr-bin-env-ln-too-many-levels-of-symbolic-links) and [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825565/sidekiq-deploy-to-multiple-environments), but unable to sort it out.

Can someone please help me resolve this?

Also, please let me know if I missed any details.

Comment: check if something on this question helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491074/usr-bin-env-ln-too-many-levels-of-symbolic-links?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I tried it already as in [SO1] and it is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like possibly `tmp/pid/sidekiq.pid` is linked to itself, thus `Too many levels of symbolic links`.

Comment: This is what the link is : `/application/current/tmp/pids -> /application/shared/tmp/pids` The pids folder inside `current` is linked to the one inside the `shared` folder.